# C++ WinInet and Callback isn't working

Tags: c++, wininet

I'm using `WinInet` and `InternetOpenUrl` to download a file... which is working. But I want to monitor the progress so I tried to add a Callback function but for some reason it's never called...

The code:

```
void CALLBACK DownloadProgress(HINTERNET hInternet, DWORD_PTR dwContext, DWORD dwInternetStatus, LPVOID lpvStatusInformation, DWORD dwStatusInformationLength)
{
    // this function never gets called
    MessageBox(NULL, L"test", L"test", MB_OK);
}

void Download()
{
    HINTERNET hOpen = InternetOpen(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, 0, 0, 0);
    InternetSetStatusCallback(hOpen, DownloadProgress);
    HINTERNET hOpenUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hOpen, L"http://www.website.com/test.txt", 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // small edit

    InternetReadFile(hOpenUrl, data, SIZE, &size);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385120(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK InternetSetStatusCallback(
  _In_ HINTERNET                hInternet,
  _In_ INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK lpfnInternetCallback
);
```

> **Note**  The callback function specified in the lpfnInternetCallback
>   parameter will not be called on asynchronous operations for the
>   request handle when the **dwContext parameter** of HttpOpenRequest is set
>   to zero (INTERNET_NO_CALLBACK), or the connection handle when the
>   **dwContext handle** of InternetConnect is set to zero
>   (INTERNET_NO_CALLBACK).

In your case, you are using `InternetOpenUrl` (after calling `InternetOpen`) which is an easy alternative to work with URLs when you not need to access the particulars of the protocol. Syntax:

```
HINTERNET InternetOpenUrl(
  _In_ HINTERNET hInternet,
  _In_ LPCTSTR   lpszUrl,
  _In_ LPCTSTR   lpszHeaders,
  _In_ DWORD     dwHeadersLength,
  _In_ DWORD     dwFlags,
  _In_ DWORD_PTR dwContext
);
```

`dwContext` is an application-defined value that's passed to the callback function registered with `InternetSetStatusCallback`. Is used to identify the application context.

Now, note that you are passing `dwContext=0` to this function in your code. If you change that, your code will work as you expect.